# Search directory where search term contains only part of the file name

Tags: vb.net

How to find all files in directory when only part of the file name is known.

I've play lists downloaded from the internet. Some file name are complete and easy to find using

```
getfiles(searchString)
```

but others have words missing from the beginning or the middle of the file name. Complicating matters even more, many of the file names contain the same words differing in placement of a word within the title and others have the addition of an extra word which is included in the result when wild card character is used in place of the missing words.

What a mouthful.

I need to be able to enter the known file name words into a variable, like one enters the search term into the File Explorer file search utility, and have the best matches returned.

I've tried using

```
location.Getfile("*term0*term1*term3*.mp3")
```

This results in a hit and miss result. It can include names that should not be included. This usually results in files that should have been moved but have not. I can take the same search term (- the *) and put it into the File Explorer search and it returns only the correct file, highlighting the matched words and the unmatched words un-highlighted.

I've tried Regex as follows:
Files are:

```
A Day with Phil Harris.mp3
A Dog for the Kids.mp3
A Fight in the Market.mp3
A Job with Rexall for Willie.mp3

For Each Itm in location.GetFiles()
    FoundMatch = Regex.IsMatch(itm.Name, "\b(?:Day|with|A)\b", 
        RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
Next
```

This returns all 4 files because each file contains at least 1 word. If the result was best match which included the entire search term and left out the lesser matches, I could trap the result in the for each.

I've also considered looping and recursive seach of results trying to refine the final result to only the file name with the most matched words. I'm sure this would work but it seems to be more work than it should be. (For computer not me, once code is written)

I've searched the web, phrasing and rephrasing my search terms. I've learned a lot over the last 24 hours but not what I'm really am after.

Any ideas, suggestions, pointers, etc. to get me going in the correct direction? They would be gratefully appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The time consuming part is accessing the files on the disk. Counting the words is peanuts for the computer. You can increase speed by reusing the same compiled regex:

```
'Before the loop!
Regex regex = New Regex("\b(?:Day|with|A)\b",
    RegexOptions.Compiled Or RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

Then inside the loop

```
Dim matches = regex.Matches(itm.Name)
```

---

You could use a list containing the filenames with the most matches

```
Dim found As New List(Of String)
Dim bestMatchCount As Integer = 0

Dim regex = New Regex("\b(?:Day|with|A)\b",
    RegexOptions.Compiled Or RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
For Each Itm In location.GetFiles()
    Dim matches = regex.Matches(Itm.Name)
    If matches.Count > bestMatchCount Then
        found.Clear() ' Remove any previously added not so good matches
        bestMatchCount = matches.Count
    End If
    found.Add(Itm.Name)
Next
```